# How to stream Spotify songs through server?

Tags: audio-streaming, spotify, audio-player

I'm currently building a part of a site that will include Spotify streaming service. Now all I want to do is stream music through the site and not through the local player. I've been looking at the web player code but I haven't had any luck trying to understand it.

Having the ability to play through only the website is a necessity. I know there's the Spotify play button widget but this causes other issues, since it doesn't go through the web player; it goes through the local client.

If I've missed the answer to this elsewhere, can you please point me in the right direction?

Comment: I think Spotify might want you to talk to them about a license before doing something like this!

Comment: Indeed - Unless you're using the Play Button widget, this is absolutely against Spotify's Terms of Service. (I work at Spotify)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about violating Spotify's Terms and Conditions

Answer (score 0):

At the moment there is no JS API that you can use to play music on your site, served from Spotify.

The Spotify Play Button will try to do the playback through the desktop client if it is installed, and will default to the Spotify web player otherwise, which will open in a new tab. This is done automatically.